# 1D Convolution vector multiplication in ANSI C code

Tags: performance, c, signal-processing, compiler

I have a code snippet here about 1D convolution in pure `ANSI C` code.

**Question:**

Is this most optimized C code, or can it be done in a more optimized way?
In my opinion, I have remove all unnecessary statements and iteration. But is it enough?

The optimization priority is: **Speed**

```
#include <stdint.h>

/*
 * 1D Convolution vector multiplication
 * a[row_a] - Input
 * k[row_k] - Input
 * 
 * b_full[row_a + row_k - 1]    - Output
 * b_same[row_a]                - Output
 * b_valid[row_a - row_k + 1]   - Output
 */
void conv(const float a[], const float k[], float b[], const size_t row_a, const size_t row_k, const CONV_SHAPE shape) {
    /* Variables */
    size_t i, j, idx, i_j;

    /* Select 1D convolution */
    switch (shape) {
    case CONV_SHAPE_FULL: {
        const size_t row_a_row_k_minus_1 = row_a + row_k - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < row_a_row_k_minus_1; i++) {
            b[i] = 0.0f;
            for (j = 0; j < row_k; j++) {
                i_j = i - j;
                if (i >= j && i_j < row_a) {
                    b[i] += a[i_j] * k[j];
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case CONV_SHAPE_SAME: {
        const size_t padding = row_k / 2;
        for (i = 0; i < row_a; i++) {
            b[i] = 0.0f;
            for (j = 0; j < row_k; j++) {
                idx = i >= padding ? i - padding + j : j;
                if (idx < row_a) {
                    b[i] += a[idx] * k[j];
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case CONV_SHAPE_VALID: {
        const size_t result_length = row_a >= row_k ? row_a - row_k + 1 : 0;
        for (i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {
            b[i] = 0.0f;
            for (j = 0; j < row_k; j++) {
               b[i] += a[j] * k[j];
            }

            /* Next row */
            a++;
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

And a working example

```
typedef enum {
    CONV_SHAPE_FULL,
    CONV_SHAPE_SAME,
    CONV_SHAPE_VALID
}CONV_SHAPE;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {

    /* Input */
    const float input[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    
    /* Output */
    float output[7];  

    /* Kernel */
    const float kernel[] = { 0.5, 1.0, 0.5 };

    /* Full */
    conv(input, kernel, output, 5, 3, CONV_SHAPE_FULL);
    printf("Full:\n");
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%f ", output[i]);
    }

    /* Same */
    conv(input, kernel, output, 5, 3, CONV_SHAPE_SAME);
    printf("\n\nSame:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%f ", output[i]);
    }

    /* Valid */
    conv(input, kernel, output, 5, 3, CONV_SHAPE_VALID);
    printf("\n\nValid:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%f ", output[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @pacmaninbw Is it better now?

Comment: Yes it is better now.

Comment: No, this is not the most optimized way to apply a convolution. You need to get rid of the conditions inside the loops, as I told you before. I also pointed you to to this post that explains how to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063757/7328782 —— Your “valid” is the only fast convolution. The other two will be really slow in comparison. For all three modes, you need to do the “valid” loop, then add separate loops with conditions for the remainder of the samples for “same” and “full”.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Look at my answer.  There is no if-statements there.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I will try this 1D convolution with 2D gaussian kernel.

Comment: Since the optimization priority is speed, can you use SIMD intrinsics?

Comment: @harold Perhaps I can, but that's the next step for hardware specific programming. Right now it's ANSI C code i'm writing.

Answer (score 3):

This a tricky question. 1-D convolution has been intensively studied (since it's the basis for FIR filtering) and it's a fairly complex problem. The best algorithms depends on

1. Relative size of filter and kernel
2. Absolute size filter and kernel
3. Are the size equal or close to a power of 2 (which makes FFT and circular addressing a lot more efficient).
4. Stream-based vs one-shot. Do you need to maintain state between continuous signal frames?
5. Can you control where the input is placed or do you have accept a pointer from "wherever".

Obviously there are A LOT of dependencies on the actual hardware: vectorization, SIMD, pipeline length and breaking penalties, threading, cashing, loop overhead, cash consideration, etc. There is no single "fastest" code, whatever may be faster on platform A maybe slower on platform B.

For simplicity I will refer to the "kernel" here as the shorter one.

As a rough guideline:

1. If the kernel are short-ish (< 100), direct convolution tends to be fastest
2. If both kernel and signal are longer and about equally long a single frequency domain multiplication works well
3. If the kernel is long-ish (>100) but a lot shorter than the signal or the signal is continuous stream , than overlap add is the way to go.

Hybrids of these are possible: you can split a kernel of 1034 samples into an FFT based convolution of length 1024 and a direct convolution with a 10 sample kernel.

Answer (score 1):

## Use an FFT to do the convolution if the kernel is large

> The optimization priority is: **Speed**

For very small kernels, your solution is probably fine. But the problem is that it scales as the product of the size of the two input arrays. If the kernel is very large though, that can make it quite slow. However, the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) states that you can do a simpler point-wise multiplication after doing a fast Fourier transform. The overhead is of course transforming both inputs, and after doing the convolution, transforming it back. But the FFT approach will be faster for kernels larger than approximately the log of the size of the signal.

## Use `restrict` if possible

One issue in C is that pointers passed to a function are allowed to alias each other. For example, the caller could make `b` point to the same array as `a` or `k`. So in this piece of code for example:

```
b[i] = 0.0f;
for (j = 0; j < row_k; j++) {
    b[i] += a[j] * k[j];
}
```

The compiler must assume that any write to `b[i]` might invalidate any value in `a[]` and `k[]`. In particular, it can no longer efficiently vectorize this code to work on multiple elements of `b[]`, `a[]` and `k[]` at the same time. The way around this is to use the [`restrict`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) keyword. It has only been introduced in C99 however.

## Avoid conditional statements where possible

You should avoid conditional statements, as branch mispredictions and pipeline stalls can have serious impacts on performance. Especially if `k[]` is much smaller than `a[]`, consider that most of the result will be in the "valid" region. So ideally, for `CONV_SHAPE_FULL` and `CONV_SHAPE_SAME`, you handle the first and last parts that are not fully valid separately, and then have the same simple loop as in `CONV_SHAPE_VALID` for the inner part.

## Missing `#include` for `size_t`

[`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is not defined in `<stdint.h>`, instead you need to include another header for it, like `<stddef.h>`.

If you want to ensure your code is really ANSI C compliant, turn on pedantic warnings and if possible specify the C standard to use. For GCC and Clang, you can use `-std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -W -Werror`.

Comment: Se my answer too.

Comment: Good comments, except about the FFT. The FFT method is only faster if the kernel is very large. Then you say “for larger inputs that is going to be faster”, but this is not true either. For larger kernel, yes. For larger signal, no. The FFT scales as O(n log n), whereas the direct convolution scales as O(n), with n the length of the signal. So the larger the signal, the less efficient the FFT method is, relative to the direct method.

Comment: More correctly it would be \$O(N \log N + M \log M)\$ for the FFT and \$O(N \cdot M)\$ for the direct method, where \$N\$ is the length of the signal and \$M\$ the length of the kernel. So FFT starts paying off when \$M > \log N\$, plus minus the constant factors of each approach.

Comment: The FFT method is independent of M, because you must pad the kernel to the size of N before FFTing. And the constant factors for the FFT are quite large. It’s C M > log N, where C is some constant that you’d have to figure out.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: that's not correct. You only need to pad to twice the kernel length $2M$ and simply process the longer dimension in chunks of $M$ using overlap add method. No need for long FFTs for a long signal.

Comment: @Hilmar yes, you can process in pieces, that’s fair.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an answer that does not contain any `if-statements`.
This requries more memory.

```
/*
 * 1D Convolution vector multiplication
 * a[row_a] - Input
 * k[row_k] - Input
 * 
 * b_full[row_a + row_k - 1]    - Output
 * b_same[row_a]                - Output
 * b_valid[row_a - row_k + 1]   - Output
 */
void conv(const float a[], const float k[], float b[], const size_t row_a, const size_t row_k, const CONV_SHAPE shape) {
    /* Variables */
    size_t i, j;

    /* Select 1D convolution */
    switch (shape) {
    case CONV_SHAPE_FULL: {
        const size_t padding = row_k - 1;
        const size_t row_a1 = row_a + 2 * padding;
        const size_t row_b = row_a + row_k - 1;
        memset(b, 0, row_b * sizeof(float));
        float* a1 = (float*)malloc(row_a1 * sizeof(float));
        memset(a1, 0, row_a1 * sizeof(float));
        memcpy(a1 + padding, a, row_a * sizeof(float));
        float* a2 = a1;
        for (i = 0; i < row_b; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < row_k; j++) {
                b[i] += a1[j] * k[j];
            }

            /* New row */
            a1++;
        }

        /* Free */
        free(a2);
        break;
    }
    case CONV_SHAPE_SAME: {
        const size_t padding = (row_k - 1) / 2;
        const size_t row_a1 = row_a + 2 * padding;
        memset(b, 0, row_a * sizeof(float));
        float* a1 = (float*)malloc(row_a1 * sizeof(float));
        memset(a1, 0, row_a1 * sizeof(float));
        memcpy(a1 + padding, a, row_a * sizeof(float));
        float* a2 = a1;
        for (i = 0; i < row_a; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < row_k; j++) {
                b[i] += a1[j] * k[j];
            }

            /* New row */
            a1++;
        }

        /* Free */
        free(a2);

        break;
    }
    case CONV_SHAPE_VALID: {
        const size_t result_length = row_a >= row_k ? row_a - row_k + 1 : 0;
        memset(b, 0, result_length * sizeof(float));
        for (i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < row_k; j++) {
                b[i] += a[j] * k[j];
            }

            /* Next row */
            a++;
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Make the `malloc` outside the loop over the image lines (assuming you’re going to apply the 1D convolution to image lines and columns for a separable 2D convolution), so that you only malloc once for the whole image. When you do image columns, you’ll need to adjust the copy, but the convolution loop remains identical.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you. But does malloc really take so much performance?

Comment: It should still be possible to do this without having to allocate any memory in `conv()`, and still avoid conditionals, by not having a single `for`-loop, but splitting it into multiple ones for the start, middle and end. Also, you could have the `switch`-statement only do the copying (if necessary) and setting up the range to loop over, and move the `for`-loop itself out of the `switch`-statement, thereby reducing code duplication.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I don't know how to do that